# Prices Turn Higher

Tags: idioms

I have a question about the phrase "*prices turn higher*" [here](http://money.cnn.com/2012/07/19/news/economy/gas-prices/):

> Crude ***prices turned higher*** at the end of June as sanctions imposed on Iran over its nuclear program by the U.S. and EU took effect.

Is it standard English to write "*prices turn higher*"?  Or is it just wall street lingo?

Comment: It is normal English.  See [turn](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/turn) sense 11

Comment: *Turn higher* is not an everyday phrase in American English when referring to price increase. It may well be financial lingo. But the article also uses a half dozen other words to indicate an increase in prices, so part of it may be avoiding repetition, which is a good thing, even in a financial article.

Answer (score 1):

This has been a common usage in financial markets since the 1930s; the earliest use I have found is in a [USDA report](http://books.google.com/books?id=_NZGAQAAIAAJ&q=%22prices+turned+higher%22&dq=%22prices+turned+higher%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5h85VNrUBMmUyQTpvILgBA&ved=0CDQQ6AEwBQ) from 1924:

> Since that time timothy prices have averaged well below the corresponding prices in either 1924 or 1923 till at the close of 1924-25 when prices turned higher on light receipts and prospects of a shorter crop.

It is a natural metaphor to describe a change of direction in price 'movements'.